# Partially Opened Sliding Drawer

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I want a widget like SlidingDrawer which is already provided by android.But I want some additional features like

1. Partially open
2. I can programmatically open sliding drawer(not full) but upto an extent which i want.something like slidingdrawer.open(int position) this method will open the sliding drawer that many pixels.

Thanks For Your Valuable Reply.

Comment: set it's height in xml, then it will open up to that height only

Comment: But I want drag feature also.so that user can open it upto an extent he want.and also i want drawer to be closed and opened partially by calling method open(int pixels);

Comment: try to set layout params dynamically, at time wrap conetnt or fill parent , then the pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the github project. Which will fulfill the needs.
[Partial Opening Sliding Drawer](https://github.com/AshwinNBhanushali/Partial-SlidingDrawer)